# How do I mock out location from the router when using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following code...

```
 <BrowserRouter>
     <Switch>
         <Route path='/' exact component={Main} />
         <Route path='/transcript' component={Transcript} />
     </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>

// Inside Transcript...
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    if(!params.get("id")){
        throw new Error("Transcript must have id");
    }
    ...
}
// Test
describe("<Transcript />", ()=>{
    beforeAll(()=>{
        context.trans = shallow(<Transcript />)
    });
    it("Simple Test", ()=>{
        expect(context.trans.find("audio")).toBeDefined()
    })
});
```

When I try to run I get an error saying the param is missing. Now since I am not using the browser I am not sure how to mock this information. Specifically, how do I mock out the location.search variable?

Comment: What exactly are you testing? If you're testing Transcript, just pass in a test double for the location prop.

Comment: Added more info

Comment: That makes no sense; you don't pass *any* props in the test.

Comment: Oh, you are using `location` from the global scope (aka `window`). I was expecting you would be using location from the router.

Answer (score 2):

One option is dependency injection: allow `location` (or perhaps even `search`) to be passed as a prop to your component. You can give the prop a value of `window.location` by default, and in the test pass a specific value. However, then you aren't testing that the default value is correct :).

So If you want to test that your function is retrieving a value from window.location it's a bit trickier. Older versions of jsDOM (7 and earlier) allowed you to define properties on location as such:

```js
// somewhere in test setup
 Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'search', {
  writable: true,
  value: 'query=true'
});
```

But now jsDOM doesn't let you do that (as of jest 22+). There is an alternative, however. You can use the [`testURL`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#testurl-string) jest configuration property to set the url for all tests, but that doesn't work if your tests ever need a different configuration. But if you use the pushState api, then that can be used to set the url:

```js
window.history.pushState({}, 'Test Title', '/test.html?query=true')
```

This may have caveats though if other things care about the history api, but probably works in your case.

The ideal way would be to use `jsdom.reconfigure` to set the url, but the jsdom instance used by jest is not easily accessible...

References:

- https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5124
- https://www.ryandoll.com/post/2018/3/29/jest-and-url-mocking

Answer (score 1):

As you state, the problem is that you don't have a browser, so you don't have a location.

There are a bunch of ways you can solve this, the easiest is to provide a mock location object just before your test:

```
it("Simple Test", ()=>{
   global.location = new URL('your.mock.com')
   expect(context.trans.find("audio")).toBeDefined()
 })
```

However, if this isn't relevant to the test (and you just need it to make your component not blow up) then you should probably check that `window && window.location` is available before checking for `params` instead.